# Mysql Insert query not working in php scripts - permission issue?

Tags: permissions

#### Problem Description

I cannot write to a Mysql table using php. Native command line using mysql client works. But I can make "select" in all variants - seems like a permission problem, but what kind? the mysql credentials are the same

I have a fresh Debian 7.6 installed with Apache, PHP and Mysql all from repositories. PHP is special, my application needs PHP 5.3. (Original 7.6 repo has only php 5.4). So I installed PHP like suggested in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/507857/110121).

#### Tests

Installed packages:

```
root@{servername}:/var/www# dpkg -l | grep php
ii  libapache2-mod-php5                   5.3.3-7+squeeze19                  amd64        server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apache 2 module)
ii  php5                                  5.3.3-7+squeeze19                  all          server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metapackage)
ii  php5-cli                              5.3.3-7+squeeze19                  amd64        command-line interpreter for the php5 scripting language
ii  php5-common                           5.3.3-7+squeeze19                  amd64        Common files for packages built from the php5 source
ii  php5-curl                             5.3.3-7+squeeze19                  amd64        CURL module for php5
ii  php5-gd                               5.3.3-7+squeeze19                  amd64        GD module for php5
ii  php5-mysql                            5.3.3-7+squeeze19                  amd64        MySQL module for php5
ii  php5-suhosin                          0.9.32.1-1                         amd64        advanced protection module for php5
ii  php5-xmlrpc                           5.3.3-7+squeeze19                  amd64        XML-RPC module for php5
root@{servername}:/var/www# dpkg -l | grep mysql
ii  libdbd-mysql-perl                     4.021-1+b1                         amd64        Perl5 database interface to the MySQL database
ii  libmysqlclient16                      5.1.73-1                           amd64        MySQL database client library
ii  libmysqlclient18:amd64                5.5.38-0+wheezy1                   amd64        MySQL database client library
ii  mysql-client                          5.5.38-0+wheezy1                   all          MySQL database client (metapackage depending on the latest version)
ii  mysql-client-5.5                      5.5.38-0+wheezy1                   amd64        MySQL database client binaries
ii  mysql-common                          5.5.38-0+wheezy1                   all          MySQL database common files, e.g. /etc/mysql/my.cnf
ii  mysql-server                          5.5.38-0+wheezy1                   all          MySQL database server (metapackage depending on the latest version)
ii  mysql-server-5.5                      5.5.38-0+wheezy1                   amd64        MySQL database server binaries and system database setup
ii  mysql-server-core-5.5                 5.5.38-0+wheezy1                   amd64        MySQL database server binaries
ii  php5-mysql                            5.3.3-7+squeeze19                  amd64        MySQL module for php5
root@{servername}:/var/www# dpkg -l | grep apache
ii  apache2-mpm-prefork                   2.2.22-13+deb7u3                   amd64        Apache HTTP Server - traditional non-threaded model
ii  apache2-utils                         2.2.22-13+deb7u3                   amd64        utility programs for webservers
ii  apache2.2-bin                         2.2.22-13+deb7u3                   amd64        Apache HTTP Server common binary files
ii  apache2.2-common                      2.2.22-13+deb7u3                   amd64        Apache HTTP Server common files
ii  libapache-pom-java                    10-2                               all          Maven metadata for all Apache Software projects
ii  libapache2-mod-dnssd                  0.6-3                              amd64        Zeroconf support for Apache 2 via avahi
ii  libapache2-mod-php5                   5.3.3-7+squeeze19                  amd64        server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apache 2 module)
```

My PHP test script:

```
root@{servername}:/var/www# cat testscript.php 
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
error_reporting('E_ALL');

$db = mysql_connect('localhost', '{applicationname}', '{password}');
mysql_select_db('{applicationname}');

$result = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query('SELECT * from clients'));
print_r($result);
echo "\n\n";

$code = mysql_query("INSERT INTO clients VALUES ('2', 'TestEntry', 'Test xy', 0)");

$result = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query('SELECT * from clients'));
print_r($result); print_r($code);
print mysql_error(); echo "\n\n";

$code = mysql_query("DELETE FROM clients where ClientID = 2");

$result = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query('SELECT * from clients'));
print_r($result); print_r($code);
print mysql_error(); echo "\n\n";
```

Native mysql-client test

```
mysql> use {applicationname}

Database changed
mysql> select * from clients;
+----------+------------+-------------------+--------------+
| ClientID | ClientName | ClientDescription | ParentClient |
+----------+------------+-------------------+--------------+
|        1 | CPN        | Company Name      |            0 |
+----------+------------+-------------------+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO clients VALUES ('2', 'TestEntry', 'Test xy', 0);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from clients;
+----------+------------+-------------------+--------------+
| ClientID | ClientName | ClientDescription | ParentClient |
+----------+------------+-------------------+--------------+
|        1 | CPN        | Company Name      |            0 |
|        2 | TestEntry  | Test xy           |            0 |
+----------+------------+-------------------+--------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> delete from clients where ClientID=2;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from clients;
+----------+------------+-------------------+--------------+
| ClientID | ClientName | ClientDescription | ParentClient |
+----------+------------+-------------------+--------------+
|        1 | CPN        | Company Name      |            0 |
+----------+------------+-------------------+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Output of my testscript

```
root@{servername}:/var/www# php testscript.php 
Array
(
    [ClientID] => 1
    [ClientName] => CPN
    [ClientDescription] => Company Name
    [ParentClient] => 0
)

Array
(
    [ClientID] => 1
    [ClientName] => CPN
    [ClientDescription] => Company Name
    [ParentClient] => 0
)
1

Array
(
    [ClientID] => 1
    [ClientName] => CPN
    [ClientDescription] => Company Name
    [ParentClient] => 0
)
1
```

#### Conclusions (so far)

PHP does not throw any error in mysql_error(), assuming no error happened. Return code is also fine from mysql_query(). There must be something like a server-level permission application.

Does this debian has apparmor or selinux enabled? I can't find /selinux/setenforce (no file)

In which logs should I look into? /var/www/mysql* is all empty.

Comment: Actually `mysql_error()` is on the wrong place. I will recheck this. (currently i dont get informations about the insert query, its the select below)

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is a bit circular... Can you try something like the following? Your php tests appear to indicate that the `INSERT` and `DELETE` **both** worked (EG: `print_r(true) == 1`).

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
error_reporting('E_ALL');

$db = mysql_connect('localhost', '{applicationname}', '{password}');
mysql_select_db('{applicationname}');

echo "--Initial Select\n--";
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query('SELECT * from clients'));
var_dump($result);

echo "--Initial Insert\n--";
$code = mysql_query("INSERT INTO clients VALUES ('2', 'TestEntry', 'Test xy', 0)");
var_dump($code);
var_dump(mysql_error());

echo "--Select after Insert\n--";
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query('SELECT * from clients'));
var_dump($result);

echo "--Delete\n--";
$code = mysql_query("DELETE FROM clients where ClientID = 2");
var_dump($code);
var_dump(mysql_error());

echo "--select after deletion--\n";
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query('SELECT * from clients'));
var_dump($result);
```